# Compare one column against multiple columns for a match, quit if no more columns exsist

Tags: vba, excel

**Problem:** Make a loop that creates an array of all cells under a column,  for each column on a sheet.

I am trying to make a script that will compare data from a column on one sheet, against multiple columns, until there are no more columns. Once I find a match I report the header to the first sheet, if I don't find a match I report "No Match".

Right now I have the logic to go through one column and report the outcome, but I'm not sure how to create a loop to compares against each consecutive column on the sheet. I have comments where I think I have gone wrong.

Thanks in advance for any dvice or direction.

Thanks,

Example Data:

[SHEET1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3boz1.png)

[SHEET2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmPDv.png)

```
Sub compareColumns()
Dim a As Long, arrA As Variant, arrB As Variant, dict As Object, c As Long, l As Long, cList As String


Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.Dictionary")
dict.comparemode = vbTextCompare

' Build the dictionary to compare with other columns
With Worksheets("sheet1")
    With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A1:A100"))
        arrA = .Cells.Value2
    End With
    For a = LBound(arrA, 1) + 2 To UBound(arrA, 1) 'LBound(arrA, 1)+2 to skip the column header and leave a space to put a result
        dict.Item(arrA(a, 1)) = arrA(a, 1)
    Next a
End With

cList = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Column.Count

With Worksheets("sheet2")
    For l = 0 To cList
        With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Cells(1, l)) 'NOT SURE IF THIS WORKS WITH CELLS
            arr(l) = .Cells.Value2 ' NOT SURE HOW TO MAKE ARRAYS FROM A LOOP
        End With
    Next l
End With

' C for compare, check against a column and if not match go to the next column, if match type result
For c = LBound(arrA, 1) + 2 To UBound(arrA, 1) 'LBound(arrA, 1)+2 to skip the column header and leave room for result
        If dict.Item(arrA(c, 1)) <> arrB(c - 1, 1) Then 'had to -1 the c to make up for the space that are in the columns
            ' GO TO THE NEXT COLUMN OR ARRAY CHECK
            Exit For
        End If

Next c

With Worksheets("sheet1")
    .Cells(2, 1).Value = arrB(1, 1) 'UPDATE EACH COLUMN
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: There might be an easier way to do this than to do in VBA. 
In sheet 1, concatenate the values to a string 
In sheet 2, for each column, concatenate the values to a string
Then in sheet 1, do a VLOOKUP.

Comment: I looked into this but it only allows for 32 cells when using =CONCATENATE, and the list could be more then this.

Comment: =CONCAT(A4:A198), as an example worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a VBA solution could be the following:

```
Sub main()
    Dim strngToMatch As String
    Dim cell As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        strngToMatch = Join(Application.Transpose(.Range("A3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value), "")
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For Each cell In .Range("A1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            If strngToMatch = Join(Application.Transpose(.Range(cell.Offset(1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, cell.Column).End(xlUp)).Value), "") Then
                Worksheets("Sheet01").Range("A2").Value = cell.Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

which can be refactored not to clutter the "main" code as follows:

```
Sub main()        
    With Worksheets("Sheet01")
        .Range("A2").Value = Join(Application.Transpose(.Range("A3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value), "")
    End With
End Sub

Function GetHeader(shtName As String, strngToMatch As String) As String
    Dim cell As Range

    With Worksheets(shtName)
        For Each cell In .Range("A1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            If strngToMatch = Join(Application.Transpose(.Range(cell.Offset(1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, cell.Column).End(xlUp)).Value), "") Then
                GetHeader = cell.Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
End Function
```

where the "main" code is quite ready to host a loop over "FACT" columns

Comment: Great, man this really helped out, didn't know about Join very useful. Thanks for all the help on this.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I did. On the first sheet
[image: Sheet 1]

On the second sheet

[image: Sheet 2]

and finally do a match 
in the first sheet
=IF( ISNUMBER(MATCH(B3, Sheet2!A2:D2, 0)), "MATCH", "NO MATCH")

Comment: For some reason the =CONCAT(B4:B8) throws an error for me (#Value?). But looking at the check, I would need it to report the header of the matched column, as these columns are added in by another script.